# Does the division of two float numbers being-1.0 mean they are equal but oppositely signed?

Tags: floating-point, precision

Due to precision, `0.1 + 0.2` is not equal to `0.3` in most programming languages. However,

```
var float a, float b
assert(a != 0 && b != 0)
if a / b == -1.0 {
    // a, b are opposite numbers:
    //  abs(a) == abs(b) && (a > 0 && b < 0 || a < 0 && b > 0)
    ...
}
```

is it **always true** if non-zero `a` and `b` are opposite numbers(their absolute value are the same, but one is positive and the other is negative).

Or I have to introduce a very small number `epsilon`(e.g. 1e-7) to eliminate the error:

```
if a / b >= -1.0 - epsilon && a / b <= -1.0 + epsilon
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it is not true that `a/b` = −1 ⇔ `a` = −`b`. As the sample code in the question suggests, this does not hold for `a` = 0, `b` = 0, since `a/b` yields NaN. Another case is `a` = ±∞, `b` = ∓∞, for which `a/b` also yields NaN.

Another case occurs in formats using a base greater than two. Consider a two-digit decimal-base format. With `a` = −1.0•10<sup>2</sup> and `b` = +9.9•10<sup>1</sup>, `a`/`b` is −1.0101010…, and rounding that (with round-to-nearest) to two digits yields −1.0, so `a/b` is −1.

In a base-two format with rounding upward or toward zero, taking `a` = −1 and `b` = the next representable value greater than −1, will produce −1 for `a/b`, as described below.

Excluding these cases (NaN quotients, bases greater than two, and rounding upward at −1), it is true that `a/b` = −1 ⇔ `a` = −`b`. A proof follows.

Consider any floating-point format in which finite numbers are represented as ±*d*<sub>0</sub>.*d*<sub>−1</sub>*d*<sub>−2</sub>…*d*<sub>1-*p*</sub>•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>, where *b* is a fixed base, *e* is an exponent within set limits, *p* is the precision (number of digits), and the digits *d*<sub>*i*</sub> are integers with 0 ≤ *d*<sub>*i*</sub> < *b*.

For `a` and `b` of different magnitudes, the closest `a`/`b` (note that `a/b` is the result of computing `a/b` in a floating-point operation, whereas `a`/`b` is the real-number quotient of `a` divided by `b`, without floating-point rounding) can be to −1 is if the magnitudes of `a` and `b` are adjacent numbers in the format, specifically if, for `a`, *d*<sub>*i*</sub> = *b*−1, so `a` = ±(*b*<sup>*e*+1</sup>−*b*<sup>*e*+1-*p*</sup>), and `b` = ∓*b*<sup>*e*+1</sup>. Then `a`/`b` = −1+*b*<sup>-*p*</sup>). In `a`/`b` = −1+*b*<sup>-*p*</sup>, the exact result, −1+*b*<sup>-*p*</sup>, is a full ULP (of the *e* = −1 exponent interval) away from −1, so the floating-point result of `a/b` will be −1+*b*<sup>-*p*</sup>.

However, we must also consider a case where `a` is ±b<sup>*e*</sup> and `b` is the next lower value, but negated, ∓(*b*<sup>*e*</sup>−*b*<sup>*e*-*p*</sup>). Then `a`/`b` is −b<sup>*e*</sup> / (*b*<sup>*e*</sup>−*b*<sup>*e*-*p*</sup>) = −1 / (1−*b*<sup>−*p*</sup>). This is not the closest a quotient can be to −1 without being −1, but it makes the magnitude of the quotient slightly greater than 1, putting it in an exponent interval where the ULP is larger. Even though it is more than 1 ULP of the *e* = −1 interval away from −1, the ULP in the *e* = 0 interval is *b* times larger. The quotient is slightly over 1/*b* ULP from −1. If *b* is 2, the quotient is more than ½ ULP from −1, so, with round-to-nearest, it will round to the next representable value. If *b* is any larger integer, the quotient is less than ½ ULP from −1, so it will round to −1. Therefore, `a/b` = −1 ⇔ `a` = −`b` does not hold in non-base-two formats, even excluding the NaN quotient cases. It also will not hold in base-two formats with some non-default rounding modes, such as round-toward-zero.

With a base-two format and round-toward-nearest, `a/b` = −1 implies `a` = -`b`. And the converse holds as long as `a/b` is not NaN.

Comment: I'm not sure the statement is true for all rounding modes. In the case where the format is IEEE 754 binary64, `a = -1.0`, `b = 0x1.fffffffffffffp-1` (i.e., `1 - 2^{-53}`), and the rounding attribute is `roundTowardZero`, wouldn't `a / b` give `-1.0`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Yes, and it means round-to-nearest in formats other than base two can give −1 too. I will update, thanks.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Updated, please let me know if it needs more work.

Answer (score 2):

1. As IEEE 754 [says (under 4.3 Rounding-direction attributes)](https://irem.univ-reunion.fr/IMG/pdf/ieee-754-2008.pdf):

   > Except where stated otherwise, every operation shall be performed as if it first produced an intermediate
   > result correct to infinite precision and with unbounded range, and then rounded that result according to one
   > of the attributes in this clause

   For division it isn't stated otherwise. So if non-zero a and b are opposite numbers then the infinitely precise result of `a / b` is `-1` and it's rounded to `-1`.
2. The (initially) surprising thing to me is that it also seems to be true in the opposite direction, unless I am missing something: if `a / b == -1`, then `a == -b`. For it to fail, you'd need close numbers, except with different signs. Something like (in Java terms) `float b = -Math.nextDown(a)` or `-Math.nextUp(a)`. But then their exponents cancel when dividing (or nearly cancel near powers of 2), and you end up effectively with `a = 1` and `b = -Math.nextDown(1)`, so `a / b == -1 / Math.nextDown(1) != 1`. Similar logic works for `double`.

EDIT: As Eric Postpischil's answer shows, I was indeed missing something by assuming the default rounding mode (and base 2, but I think that's more reasonable).

Answer (score 1):

> is it always true if non-zero a and b are opposite numbers (?)

Not always.

When the rounding mode changed from the common `FE_TONEAREST` to `FE_TOWARDZERO` or `FE_UPWARD`, I found various examples where the quotient was -1, yet `a != -b`.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void testf(float a, float b) {
  if (b) {
    float q = a / b;
    //printf("%.9g %.9g %.9g\n", a,b,q);
    if (q == -1.0f && a != -b) {
      printf("%.9g %.9g %.9g\n", a, b, q);
    }
  }
}

int r(void) {
  float f[] = {FLT_TRUE_MIN, FLT_MIN, 1, 2, FLT_MAX};
  size_t n = sizeof f / sizeof f[0];
  for (size_t ai = 0; ai < n; ai++) {
    float a = nextafterf(f[ai], -FLT_MAX);
    for (int aii = 0; aii < 3; aii++) {
      for (size_t bi = 0; bi < n; bi++) {
        float b = nextafterf(-a, -FLT_MAX);
        for (int bii = 0; bii < 3; bii++) {
          testf(a, b);
          b = nextafterf(b, FLT_MAX);
        }
      }
      a = nextafterf(a, FLT_MAX);
    }
  }
  puts("Done");
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
  r();
  fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
  r();
  fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
  r();
  fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
  r();
}
```

Output

```
Done
Done
0.99999994 -0.999999881 -1
...
Done
0.99999994 -0.999999881 -1
...
1 -0.99999994 -1
...
1.99999988 -1.99999976 -1
...
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

For the default rounding-mode (i.e., round-towards-nearest-ties-to-even), the statement is true provided `a/b` isn't `NaN`.

For round-toward-zero, here's a counter-example:

```
x = -2.717843e33
y =  2.7178426e33
```

With IEEE754 single-precision floats, the above two values will produce `-1` when divided with round-toward-zero; but they are not equal in absolute value.